# Spark: Intersection of Lists not working

Tags: list, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD of the form:

```
t1-> (Long, List[Long])
```

and a list of the form

```
 t2-> List[Long]
```

I need to perform union and intersection of the lists. I am trying the following code:

```
val t1 = a.map(x => (x._1, (List(x._2)))).reduceByKey(_ ++ _) 
val t2 = b.map(x => (x._1, (List(x._2)))).reduceByKey(_ ++ _).map(x => x._2).collect()
val t3intersect = t1.map(x => (x._1, (x._2.intersect(t2))))
val t3union = t1.map(x => (x._1, (x._2.union(t2))))
```

While union returns correct results, intersection is always an empty list. I am not able to identify the problem. Please help! Thanks!

Here's an example:

```
(1, List(1596, 1617, 1929, 2399, 2674))
(2, List(1702, 1785, 1933, 2054, 2583, 2913))
(3, List(1982, 2002, 2048, 2341, 2666))
```

and

```
List(2002, 2399)
```

This should return intersection:

```
(1, List(2399))
(2, List())
(3, List(2002))
```

and union:

```
(1, List(1596, 1617, 1929, 2399, 2674, 2002))
(2, List(1702, 1785, 1933, 2054, 2583, 2913, 2002, 2399))
(3, List(1982, 2002, 2048, 2341, 2666, 2399))
```

Comment: If the answers of people helped you somehow to solve your problem, maybe you should accept one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intersection code looks OK to me. It should work. Also try doing this for more clarity and maybe performance:

```
val t3intersect = t1.mapValues( _ intersect t2 )
```

**EDIT**: I don't know what is `a` and `b`, and what's the logic behind obtaining `t1` and `t2` from them, but if you initialize `t1` and `t2` in the Spark REPL as follows, for the sake of testing:

```
scala> val t1 = sc.parallelize( List(
     | (1, List(1596, 1617, 1929, 2399, 2674)),
     | (2, List(1702, 1785, 1933, 2054, 2583, 2913)),
     | (3, List(1982, 2002, 2048, 2341, 2666)) ), 2)
t1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, List[Int])] = ParallelCollectionRDD[10] at parallelize at <console>:12

scala> val t2 = List(2002, 2399)
t2: List[Int] = List(2002, 2399)
```

Then you obtain the expected results:

```
scala> val tr = t1.mapValues( _ intersect t2 )
tr: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, List[Int])] = MappedValuesRDD[12] at mapValues at <console>:16

scala> tr.collect()
res13: Array[(Int, List[Int])] = Array((1,List(2399)), (2,List()), (3,List(2002)))
```

So, watch out somewhere else for the error.

Comment: It doesn't work. Have been breaking my head over it for the whole day now. Is there some other way I could accomplish this?

Comment: Could you post the exact command sequence you are executing? Including those for creating the RDD and the List.

Comment: t1: (204, List(2049, 2097, 2674))
t2: List(2049, 2097, 2674)                                                                 Intersection: (204,List())
Union: (204,List(2049, 2097, 2674, List(2049, 2097, 2674)))                    I just realized that union is giving incorrect results as well.

Comment: Check the edit. Include if possible the original commands that create the RDD and the List, or the source of them, from `a` and `b`. Otherwise people cannot reproduce the real problem.

Comment: You were right, the error was indeed somewhere else. The t2 was turning out to be of form: Array[List[Long]] due to the collect(). It works now! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've reproduced your problematic case as follows:

```
object ItersectionList {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("ItersectionList")
    val sc = new SparkContext(spConf)

    val a = Array(
      (1, List(1596, 1617, 1929, 2399, 2674)),
      (2, List(1702, 1785, 1933, 2054, 2583, 2913)),
      (3, List(1982, 2002, 2048, 2341, 2666))
    )

    val t2 = List(2002, 2399)

    val t1 = sc.makeRDD(a).map(x => (x._1, (List(x._2)))).reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
    val t3intersect = t1.map(x => (x._1, (x._2.intersect(t2))))
    val t3union = t1.map(x => (x._1, (x._2.union(t2))))

    t3intersect.foreach(println)
    t3union.foreach(println)

  }
}
```

And the result is as follows:

```
Intersection:
(2,List())
(1,List())
(3,List())

Union: 
(2,List(List(1702, 1785, 1933, 2054, 2583, 2913), 2002, 2399))
(1,List(List(1596, 1617, 1929, 2399, 2674), 2002, 2399))
(3,List(List(1982, 2002, 2048, 2341, 2666), 2002, 2399))
```

I found it is the problem of `List(x._2)` in `map(x => (x._1, (List(x._2)))).reduceByKey(_ ++ _)`, which changes the `List(a, b, c)` to `List(List(a, b, c))`. Since `List(List(a, b, c))` does not match `List(a, b, c)`, the intersection will be null. You can remove `List()` as follows, and the result will be correct.

```
 val t1 = sc.makeRDD(a).map(x => (x._1, x._2)).reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
```

or

```
 val t1 = sc.makeRDD(a).reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
```

Comment: The error was due to the collect that I was performing for t2. It created an array[list] which was not matching with list in t1.Thanks for the help!